# How to improve image quality on blur images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am making an OCR which reads text . I am giving that cropped region to Tesseract to read it. As those cropped images are very small and blurry, Tesseract is unable to read them. When it can read them, it gives wrong predictions. I think that by improving image quality of cropped images, these problems can be solved. I've tried many method to remove the background color into white but it blur the text.  How would I go about improving such images? I'm working on this sort of images.https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILBzG.jpg

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific about your inputs and your goal. What do you want to extract? All text blindly? Or key-value pairs, like "Profession": "Salaried Person"? Are your images generally of a fixed format (i.e., Customer Demographics form) like in your link? Or any type of form (e.g., has boxes but not necessarily Customer Demographics)? Fixed font / font family? Anything that can be relied on?

Comment: I want to extract all the text present on the image , my images are  in a fixed format just wanted to know how can I improve image any code which improves the image would be helpful

Comment: The starting quality of this image is pretty bad. And you'll have to put in a LOT of effort to try to get accurate text out of it. I would focus on getting better starting images. Preferrably higher resolution and in PNG (lossless) format instead of JPG (format).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to work on these sort of images.

Comment: Is there any solution before doing OCR, cleaned the background noise or remove gray background colour? Also bold the text

Comment: *that* resolution is unusable for OCR. if you *have to* solve this, you need to work with neural networks and you will likely have to train them. this can't be solved by magic low level image processing effects. just tell whoever gave you this task that it's impossible for a machine at this time, and to just pay people for the data entry job.

Comment: #Christoph Rackwitz  forget OCR is it possible to bold the text or change the background color without effecting text?